# How to exclude rows based on certain values and duplicates

Tags: mysql

We have data related to subscription events - `create`, `update`, `delete`, etc.  I want to be able to query on this data based on certain values to determine if a given user was active on a given date based on the events logged.  I have the following table: ([SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63b6bb/1))

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  eid varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  cid varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  sid varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  event_type varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  period_start datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  period_end datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  date date DEFAULT NULL,
  datetime datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (eid)
);
```

with the following example data:

```
INSERT INTO events
  (eid, cid, sid, event_type, period_start, period_end, date, datetime)
VALUES
  ('event_1', 'customer_1', 'subscription_456', 'created', '2016-03-11 17:38:50', '2016-09-11 18:38:50', '2016-03-11', '2016-03-11 17:38:51');
  ('event_2', 'customer_1', 'subscription_456', 'updated', '2016-09-11 18:38:50', '2017-03-11 17:38:50', '2016-09-11', '2016-09-11 18:46:04'),
  ('event_3', 'customer_1', 'subscription_456', 'deleted', '2016-09-11 18:38:50', '2017-03-11 17:38:50', '2016-09-11', '2016-09-11 22:39:43'),
```

I am looking for a query where I could enter in any date to see if this user was active during this time based on the `period_start`, `period_end`, and `event_type`.

**Basically, if a row exists with `event_type = 'deleted'`, then it should exclude that row and any other rows with the same `sid`, `period_start` and `period_end` values.** I have tried:

```
SELECT e.* FROM events e
JOIN (SELECT sid, event_type, period_start, period_end
    FROM events) e2
    ON
        (e2.sid = e.sid AND e2.event_type = "deleted"
        AND e2.period_start = e.period_start
        AND e2.period_end = e.period_end)
    WHERE
        (e.event_type = 'created' OR e.event_type = 'updated')
        AND date(e.period_start) <= '2016-04-01'
        AND date(e.period_end) >= '2016-04-01';
```

which should return the `created` event (but isn't returning anything), while using the dates `2016-09-01` or `2017-01-01` should return nothing.  I'm not sure what to try next.  I'd really like to be able to accomplish this in a query rather than having to process the data in PHP or JS.

Comment: According to your sample data, there should be no result. Unless there is a typo error in your sample data. dates

Comment: The `deleted` should cancel out the `updated` because `event_3`'s `period_start` and `period_end` are the same as `event_2`'s.  Again, not even sure if this is possible in SQL alone but I thought I'd give it a shot first.

Comment: What do you mean by *should discount any other rows* ? a: deleted rows should be ignored - or b: only deleted rows are to be considered - or c: deleted rows are more important (how?) -or d: something else (please elaborate).

Comment: `deleted` rows should be excluded from the query _as well as_ any `updated` rows with the same `period_start` and `period_end` values as the `deleted` row

Answer (score 1):

As you have now added a description of how you want deleted information excluded I suggest the following:

```
SELECT  e.eid, e.cid, e.sid, e.event_type, e.period_start, e.period_end, e2.eid, e2.event_type
FROM events e
left join events e2
       on e.sid = e2.sid and e.event_type <> 'deleted' and e2.event_type = 'deleted'
       AND e.period_start = e2.period_start AND e.period_end = e2.period_end
WHERE e.event_type <> 'deleted'
AND e2.eid IS NULL
AND  '2016-04-01' between e.period_start and e.period_end
```

---

Previous answer:
I really don't know what you want, perhaps it would help if you listed the a set of parameters, and then listed the expected result for those?

In the absence of that perhaps this will help:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM events e
WHERE '2016-04-01' between e.period_start and e.period_end
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bc4be/1/0)**:

```
|     eid |        cid |              sid | event_type |            period_start |                  period_end |                    date |                datetime |
|---------|------------|------------------|------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| event_1 | customer_1 | subscription_456 |    created | March, 11 2016 17:38:50 | September, 11 2016 18:38:50 | March, 11 2016 00:00:00 | March, 11 2016 17:38:51 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT  e.eid, e.cid, e.sid, e.event_type, e.period_start, e.period_end, e2.eid, e2.event_type
FROM events e
left join events e2
       on e.sid = e2.sid and e.event_type <> 'deleted' and e2.event_type = 'deleted'
WHERE '2016-04-01' between e.period_start and e.period_end
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bc4be/1/1)**:

```
|     eid |        cid |              sid | event_type |            period_start |                  period_end |     eid | event_type |
|---------|------------|------------------|------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|---------|------------|
| event_1 | customer_1 | subscription_456 |    created | March, 11 2016 17:38:50 | September, 11 2016 18:38:50 | event_3 |    deleted |
```

Comment: I think I'm close.  `SELECT e.eid, e.cid, e.sid, e.event_type, e.period_start, e.period_end FROM events e LEFT JOIN events e2 ON e.sid = e2.sid AND e2.event_type = 'deleted' AND e.event_type = 'updated' AND '2016-10-01' BETWEEN e.period_start AND e.period_end` will select the correct rows that should be excluded, so if I do a `LEFT Excluding JOIN` (https://www.codeproject.com/kb/database/visual_sql_joins.aspx) then it _should_ return the rows I'm looking for I think.  Tinkering with this idea now...

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is broken at given sample data.

However it is important to debug at which line SQL stops to return values:

See the following example, there is still one line returned at the highlighted part of SQL

[image]

However if you run the additional 2 lines at the end, there will be no result, and you will need to double check why? Because no data will match after SQL line #11